# Lock website in vertical position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I have a mobile version of a website in the vertical position.
Is it possible to block the website? When you turn the phone horizontal, page still locked on vertical position.

If so, I ask for advice, because my attempts to do so using css were unsuccessful. Thank you.

Comment: And it's a bad idea.. Better use the `orientation` in `@media` queries and change your styles

Answer (score 0):

try this media query it should work

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

[original reference](https://gist.github.com/visnup/2605440)

Comment: Won't it turn completely upside down if you turn your device to the right ? And then if you turn your phone in portrait (but upside down), turn at 180deg ?

Comment: Thank you Immortal Dude but it does not work properly :(